# Query stuck in mattermost postgresql communication

Tags: postgresql, debugging

Ubuntu 18.04
PostgreSQL 10.10
Mattermost 5.15

On mattermost startup process stay forever on

> {"level":"info","ts":1570609055.2422519,"caller":"sqlstore/supplier.go:223","msg":"Pinging
>   SQL master database"}

Running this query

```
SELECT pid, age(clock_timestamp(), query_start), usename, query, state
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE query != '' AND query NOT ILIKE '%pg_stat_activity%'
ORDER BY query_start desc;
```

Gives me

```
 pid  |      age       | usename |         query         | state
------+----------------+---------+-------------------------------
 8700 | 00:08:54.84669 | mmuser  | SELECT * FROM Systems | idle
```

From there, how do I diagnose what makes this query never end ?

Comment: What do you get if you include `state` in the list of columns selected by your query?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe idle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query has already ended 9 minutes ago. PostgreSQL is sitting idle and waiting for the next statement on this connection, which isn't coming.

The block must be somewhere else in your startup process.